# How to connect two android devices over the internet for P2P communication

Tags: android, android-studio, networking, p2p

I searched alot on how to accomplish a successful P2P connection between two devices for data transfer. But wherever I went it said that it isn't possible because it requires port forwarding from the NAT. But I donot understand how the Bittorent Android App works. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

For that task I would use the www.pubnub.com framework. You could have a look at that.

Thomas

Comment: I'm sorry I checked it out and it doesn't seem like a direct P2P connection. I want a connection just like a torrent network where each device is connected to each other without a central server